# OpenLayers 4.6.5 center not working

Tags: openlayers

center is not working

https://jsfiddle.net/YuK1Game/katcr16L/8/

```
let olView = new ol.View({
    center: [35.689634, 139.692101],
    zoom: 4,
});
```

center 35.689634, 139.692101 is Tokyo in japan.
but, it not working
thanks

Comment: I referred to tutorials
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/concepts.html

Comment: Looks to me like a CRS (Coordinate Reference Systems) Issue. That centerpoint, off the coast of Africa is [0,0] and very familiar to folks working on GIS stuff

Comment: Okay I tried a few things in that fiddle and nothing works... It's bizzare

Answer (score 11):

35.689634 *apples* and 39.692101 *bananas* is not the correct coordinate for Tokyo. Every coordinate has a specific projection, without it, the data is meaningless.

The View has a projection too, which defaults to `EPSG:3857`. Your coordinate is in `EPSG:4326`(WGS84).

> The projection. Default is EPSG:3857 (Spherical Mercator)

The second error is that you mixed X and Y, it should be `[139.692101, 35.689634]`

```js
const center = ol.proj.transform([139.692101, 35.689634], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
console.log('center is:', center);

let olView = new ol.View({
  center: center,
  zoom: 4
  // default projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

let olLayers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  })
];

new ol.Map({
  layers: olLayers,
  view: olView,
  target: 'app',
});
```

```html
 <link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
  <div id="app"></div>
```